# Calculus book for people who know limits

Tags: calculus, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I have the probably slightly unusual background of being quite comfortable with real numbers, functions, limits, sequences, series, etc, but having no knowledge of calculus beyond the definitions of continuity and the derivative. Could anyone recommend an interesting book on calculus for someone with this sort of background? As opposed to, say, standard texts like Spivak's *Calculus* or Burkill's *A First Course in Mathematical Analysis*, which spend a lot of time teaching numbers, functions, limits, and sequences, and not so much time focusing on calculus *per se*, I'm interested in something that would show the beauty and perhaps a few of the applications of calculus itself, probably including multivariable calculus. Concise and reasonable rigorous (i.e. not a cookbook) would be pros too.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not skip the chapters you already know about while reading a good book like Spivak's Calculus ?

Comment: Sure, and that's what I'll do if nobody answers, but I thought there might be a perfect gem of a book out there waiting for me to find it. :-)

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Cookbooks are concise and rigorous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "reasonably concise and rigorous" I recommend the famous calculus book written by Serge Lang. [Short Calculus](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=XUjod_RjjX8C&pg=PR4&dq=calculus%20book%20written%20by%20Serge%20Lang&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=1iOqUf22M5SB0AG0uYHQCg&ved=0CEAQ6wEwAg#v=onepage&q=calculus%20book%20written%20by%20Serge%20Lang&f=false) of Original Edition of ["a First Course in Calculus''](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=xNipwIAOq2EC&pg=PR4&dq=calculus%20book%20written%20by%20Serge%20Lang&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=1iOqUf22M5SB0AG0uYHQCg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=calculus%20book%20written%20by%20Serge%20Lang&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Bressoud's [Second year calculus: From Celestial Mechanics to Special Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797606X). It covers multivariable calculus, with motivations and applications to physics, and at a more elementary level than, say, Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' Calculus may be what you're after...

It does have sections on real numbers, limits, sequences and series but also goes on in depth over several topics; including functions in Vector Space and multivariate calculus :)

There is an [online copy](http://archive.org/details/ThomasCalculus11thtextbookSolutions) however it doesn't seem to have a contents page.
Copy I have has ISBN `0-321-24335-8`; t'is a brilliant book!

Answer (score 0):

Tom Apostol's Calculus book is excellent and is considered to be a classic. It might also fit in well with what you are looking for.